# Set the FileFormat of a workbook before the user clicks SaveAs

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote some Excel macros that open a .txt file and builds a workbook, and some code to save it automatically:

```
 ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="MyReport.xlsx", FileFormat:=xlWorkbookDefault
```

Even with the .xlsx suffix on the FileName, the FileFormat is required to save as a workbook, not as text.

I want to set the FileFormat so the user can save, by clicking the normal things, but without having to remember to save as .xlsx instead of .txt.

Comment: Don't open the text file and work on the file directly, but instead import it or copy/paste it into an empty workbook.  Then the file will already be in xlsx format before the user goes to save it.

Comment: Ah! You're talking about the VBA equivalent of Data > From Text/CSV > Import > Load ... right? I tested it and found that it populates a workbook that is "already" an .xlsx  That's a great idea, and I learned something, but I don't think I'll use it this time because it introduces some other "inconveniences".

Comment: I think that's the only way though, if you want the file type to default to xlsx when the user hits Save.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the filename beforehand.

```vb
fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
    fileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")

If fileSaveName <> False Then
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fileSaveName, _
        FileFormat:=xlWorkbookDefault
End If
```

Comment: That's good code, but I don't want to execute the .SaveAs method in my program. I just want to set up the ActiveWorkbook as a "xlWorkbookDefault" so that when the user wants to save "the regular way", he will not have to remember to click "Save As .xlsx"